# Getting error from creating a Hilt viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I've tried to hand over a simple viewModel to a composable and get everytime this error and i don't know what it means:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class com.example.app.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager`

My Gradle:

```kotlin
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation:1.0.0-beta01")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
```

I've created a `BaseApplication` file

```kotlin
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class BaseApplication: Application()
```

and set it in the Manifest.

I've created an `AppModule` file:

```kotlin
import android.content.Context
import com.veloce.montageservice.BaseApplication
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApplication(@ApplicationContext app: Context): BaseApplication {
        return app as BaseApplication
    }
}
```

Then set the `@HiltAndroidApp` in my `MainActivity` and created a `viewModel` like this:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class TaskViewModel: ViewModel() {

//code

}
```

The `viewModel` is called in my navigation at the `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
 val navController = rememberNavController()
 NavHost(
     navController = navController,
     startDestination = Screens.LoginScreen.route
 ) {
 composable(Screens.ActiveMontageScreen.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
     activeTask?.let {
         val factory =
             HiltViewModelFactory(LocalContext.current, navBackStackEntry)
         val viewModel: TaskViewModel = viewModel("taskViewModel", factory)
         ActiveMontageScreen(
             viewModel = viewModel,
             task = it,
             navigation = navController,
             context = LocalContext.current
         ) {
             removeActiveTask()
         }
     }
 }
}
```

I really cant't see any problems, but I am quite unexperienced with Hilt and Android Development.
Does anyone know whats the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things misplaced as I can see, which lead to such error.

For example:

1. You're not injecting the context here `class TaskViewModel(context: Context)` if you need context in `viewmodel` then you can use `AndroidViewModel`.
2. you're creating `BaseApplication` in `AppModule` but you're not using it(Maybe used somewhere else).

You can create such viewmodel with following steps:

1. Create `BaseApplication` & register that in manifest, which you have already done.
2. Create a `AndroidViewModel` as following:

   ```
   @HiltViewModel
   class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(
    application: BaseApplication
   ) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    fun test() {
        getApplication<BaseApplication>().getString(R.string.app_name)
    }

   }
   ```

Here notice the use of `@Inject constructor` which will take the `BaseApplication` class from `AppModule`.

3. In your `MainActivity` initialize the `viewmodel` like this:

   ```
   @AndroidEntryPoint
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel: TaskViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        viewModel.test()
    }

   }
   ```

If you fail to resolve any of the hilt related things then make sure you have these dependencies in `build.gradle`

```
//Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.33-beta"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.33-beta"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-beta01"
```

Comment: That the context didnt made sense there was clear for me like 30 seconds after ive hitted the post button. :-) I've took it out and tried your suggestions but unfortunately nothing changed, same error

Comment: I've saw that the annotation in `MainActivity` was wrong an changed it. I got a new error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.app.ui.view_models.TaskViewModel`

Comment: @ChrisPi  Did you use `@Inject constructor` in `TaskViewModel`? If not then you should. Also, Did you try the method i gave you to initialize viewmodel in `MainActivity` ?

Comment: Yes, I made the changes. I'm trying to implement kapt now

Comment: I got it. The `classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.33-beta")`  and `id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")` were missing.

Comment: @ChrisPi Great. I hope you were able to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

please check these options:

1- you must have these dependencies:

```
//Hilt
def hilt_version = "2.38.1"
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version")
kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version")
kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03")
implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
```

2- you must have added this annotation into your activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity()
```

3- you must have injected your viewModel in your screen like this

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
   viewModel: MainScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

So for you viewmodel, you'll need to add the annotation @Inject or @ViewModelInject depending on your version dependency and create it like this

```
class TaskViewModel @Inject constructor(context: Context) : ViewModel() {
    //code
}
```

And in your activity of fragment Instantiate this way

```
val taskViewModel: TaskViewModel by viewmodels()
```