# Jetpack Compose Navigation with HiltViewModel: MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

I created a new composable activity project with the following dependencies:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha09"
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

Then I created two composables, one with the Hilt's view model:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen1(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Screen 1")
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Text("To Screen 2")
        }
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class Screen2ViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel()

@Composable
fun Screen2(viewModel: Screen2ViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    Text(text = "Screen 2")
}
```

It works if I try to render them. However, when I add the NavController:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screen1") {
                        composable("screen1") {
                            Screen1() {
                                navController.navigate("screen2")
                            }
                        }
                        composable("screen2") {
                            Screen2()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My app crashes when I go to the screen 2 with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class com.sample.myapplication.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
```

What am I doing wrong?

Full code:

```kotlin
package com.sample.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.sample.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screen1") {
                        composable("screen1") {
                            Screen1() {
                                navController.navigate("screen2")
                            }
                        }
                        composable("screen2") {
                            Screen2()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen1(onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Screen 1")
        Button(onClick = onClick) {
            Text("To Screen 2")
        }
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class Screen2ViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel()

@Composable
fun Screen2(viewModel: Screen2ViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    Text(text = "Screen 2")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error from creating a Hilt viewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319542/getting-error-from-creating-a-hilt-viewmodel)

Comment: I guess you are missing @AndroidEntryPoint annotation in your activity.

Comment: yes, @ AndroidEntryPoint is missing from MainActivity add @ AndroidEntryPoint above declaration of class MainActivity

Comment: It gives me the same error

Comment: Can you include your `build.gradle` files? It seems like you haven't applied the dagger plugin.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov It is not jetpack compose.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I fixes this error by adding Hilt's Gradle Plugin listed here: https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html#hilt-gradle-plugin

Now I have another error (`Hilt Activity must be attached to an @HiltAndroidApp Application`), but I think it's out of scope of this exact question. Could you please add an answer here so I can bounty it?

Comment: @Feeco - I've added an answer. You might look at the [Hilt Application docs](https://dagger.dev/hilt/application) for an explanation on why you also need a `@HiltAndroidApp` annotation on your application class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document of `HiltViewModel`

> Returns an existing HiltViewModel  -annotated ViewModel or creates a new one scoped to the current navigation graph present on the {@link NavController} back stack.
> If no navigation graph is currently present then the current scope will be used, usually, a fragment or an activity.

To fix the issue we have two solutions:

1. Use `viewModel()` from `import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel`
2. Scope the instance of `hiltViewModel()` to the activity and pass to `Screen2()`
3. Need to apply the Hilt Plugin as the next answer:
   Add some more to app `build.gradle`

- `apply plugin: kotlin-kapt`
- add hilt android compiler to dependency `kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.40"`
  Create an extension of application and anotate with `@HiltAndroidApp` and use in your app.

Comment: With the first approach, how can I inject dependencies then? 

I will try the second approach, but it looks a bit tricky. What if my Screen2 is deep down the tree? Should I pass dependencies straight down? I think it contradicts DI principles.

Comment: To inject dependencies to `ViewModel`, we can inject via constructor or properties. So you can inject by properties. You can apply in your case

Comment: Now it works but I cannot understand why do we need `hiltViewModel()` if we can use `viewModel()` then?

Comment: @Feeco Update the last approach with adding more according to @ianhanniballake. You use the `hiltViewModel()` to scope in the navigation graph

Answer (score 3):

Applying the `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation doesn't do anything itself - it is a marker annotation that allows the [Hilt Gradle Plugin](https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html#hilt-gradle-plugin) to process your code and generate the proper bytecode necessary to get Hilt working. You'll want to make sure the plugin is applied:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // other repositories...
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    // other plugins...
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.40'
  }
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'

android {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just confirm that you added `@AndroidEntryPoint` anotation on yout `Activity` and `@HiltViewModel` annotation on your `ViewModel`.

This issue will be fixed by these two updates.

Comment: I've just added `@AndroidEntryPoint` to `MainActivity` and `@HiltViewModel` to `ViewModel`. Have the same error. I also added full code section to my question.

Comment: Can you try moving view model and activities in separate classes?

Comment: Moved everything except `MainActivity` class to `Another.kt`. It gives me the same error.