# Given component holder class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, gui-testing, navigation-compose

I'm doing an app in Android/Kotlin as a portfolio, and I want to use navigation testing to do UI tests. But the app also has Hilt and I had to configure both to run the tests, using Hilt android testing.

When doing the tests, I had a series of problems, and I ended up getting stuck in this one:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class androidx.activity.ComponentActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager
//resto do erro oculto
at br.com.alura.mundobola.MainActivityKt.TelaApp(MainActivity.kt:149)
at br.com.alura.mundobola.auxiliardoteste.PreparacaoDosTestesKt.preparacaoDosTestes(PreparacaoDosTestes.kt:15)
at br.com.alura.mundobola.ui.screen.CadastroDeBolasScreenKtTest$preparaNavHostController$1.invoke(CadastroDeBolasScreenKtTest.kt:34)
at br.com.alura.mundobola.ui.screen.CadastroDeBolasScreenKtTest$preparaNavHostController$1.invoke(CadastroDeBolasScreenKtTest.kt:33)
```

This error does not run the app screen composable (the composable that is in main activity) in the test. The code is like this:

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class CadastroDeBolasScreenKtTest{
    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)
    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val testeDoNavigation = createComposeRule()
    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    @Before
    fun preparaNavHostController(){
        testeDoNavigation.setContent {
            navController = preparacaoDosTestes()
            hiltRule.inject()
        }
    }
    @Test
    fun deveMostrarFabENomeApp_QuandoEstiverNaTelaDeBolas(){
        testeDoNavigation.onNodeWithText(tituloTelaLista).assertIsDisplayed()
        //the rest I omitted
    }
}
```

preparacaoDosTestes() function, which runs the screen composable:

```
@Composable
fun preparacaoDosTestes(): TestNavHostController {
    val navController = TestNavHostController(context = LocalContext.current)
    navController.navigatorProvider.addNavigator(ComposeNavigator())
    TelaApp(navController)
    return navController
}
```

My Main Activity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MundoBolaTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    TelaApp(navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found similar issues in some forums, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69724932/jetpack-compose-navigation-with-hiltviewmodel-mainactivity-does-not-implement-i), [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242002/given-component-does-not-implement-interface-dagger-hilt-internal-generatedcompo), and [last one](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2764). Some of them saying about a navigation version compatibility issue with hilt. I had tried changing the versions and it still didn't work.

my build.gradle(app):

```
//I only left the essentials on build.gradle
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner = "br.com.alura.mundobola.ConfiguradorTesteHilt"
    }
}

dependencies {
    val navigationVersion = "2.7.3"
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.navigation/navigation-compose
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$navigationVersion")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.datastore/datastore-preferences
    implementation ("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.navigation/navigation-testing
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$navigationVersion")
    val hiltVersion = "2.48"
    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hiltVersion")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$hiltVersion")
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")
    androidTestImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:$hiltVersion")
    kaptAndroidTest("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hiltVersion")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
}
```

How can I fix this error? and in my case, is it really the version incompatibility of both libraries?

Ps: [my project on github](https://github.com/MuriTG25/Mundo-Bola/tree/pre-alpha) to take a better look at the problem