# Android Dagger Hilt problems

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm currently making a mini app to practice Android app development. My app works fine but when I tried to connect it to a local database with Room and Hilt dagger it starts crashing and spitting and I get this error message:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.franckpower.numerique, PID: 23249
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Given component holder class com.franckpower.numerique.MainActivity does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent or interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponentManager

How do we solve this?

I've followed a tired tutorial on how to set up Room with Hilt dagger but without a solution and every time my program always crashes

Please help me

Comment: Without showing your configuration files and activity will be hard to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting error from creating a Hilt viewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67319542/getting-error-from-creating-a-hilt-viewmodel) or [Given component does not implement interface dagger.hilt.internal.GeneratedComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242002/given-component-does-not-implement-interface-dagger-hilt-internal-generatedcompo)